# How to compute a power of a power using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, exponent

I've recently been looking into recursion and it's been very confusing. I'm trying to write a java program which uses recursion to generate the result of a base number to a power, which also has a height of how many exponents the base has. For example, a base of two with a power of 3 and a height of 3 will result:

> (((2^3)^3)^3)

Here is my (very flawed) code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(exponentWithHeight(2, 2, 3));
}

public static int exponentWithHeight(int base, int power, int height) {
    if (power < 0 || height < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Check input values.");
    }
    if (power == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (base * height * exponentWithHeight(base, power - 1, height - 1));
    }
}
```

I'm really not sure how to go about getting my desired output; As I said this is really confusing and new to me. Can someone help explain how to go about doing this?

Comment: What is your expected output, and what do you get instead? What did you find when you debugged it?

Comment: So my expected output when using calling the method exponentWithHeight(2, 2, 3) would be 256. Instead, I get 24. When I debug it, everything runs perfectly.

Comment: "everything runs perfectly" What do you mean? That you get 256 when you debug it? Or that you don't get any errors? (The latter is meaningless, you clearly have an error if you don't get the right result)

Comment: Remember that you can simplify a series of exponents by multiplying them together. So `(((2^3)^3)^3) = 2 ^ (3 * 3 * 3) = 2 ^ (3 ^ 3)` - effectively making your formula `f(n, exp, height) = n ^ (exp ^ height)`. Might be able to leverage that in simplifying whatever solution you come up with.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you! Didn't think of it that way.

Answer (score 1):

It is a double recursion, both on height and power.

Note that if it would make sense to have the values cached somewhere, since exponentWithHeight(base, power, 0) will be recalculated multiple times.

The result with this code is 256:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(exponentWithHeight(2, 2, 3));
}

public static int exponentWithHeight(int base, int power, int height) {
    if (power < 0 || height < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Input; Check power and/or height value.");
    }
    if (base == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (height == 0) {
        return calcPower(base, power);
    } else {
        return exponentWithHeight(calcPower(base, power), power, height - 1);
    }
}

public static int calcPower(int base, int power) {
    if (power == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return base * power(base, power - 1);
}
```

Comment: It seems as if this code doesn't calculate the values correctly; When I input  (3,2,2), instead of getting 81 as the answer I get 729. What exactly is going on when you multiply [exponentWithHeight(base, power, 0) * exponentWithHeight(base, power, height - 1)]?

Comment: edited it.  Getting the value of the first base and power.  and subtracting one from the power.

Answer (score 0):

Are we forgetting that you can multiply a series of exponents together to simplify the equation?

The following should work.

```
public static int exponentWithHeight(int base, int power, int height) {
    if (power < 0 || height < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Input; Check power and/or height value.");
    }
    if (power == 0 || height == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (int) Math.pow(base, Math.pow(power, height));
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that `Math.pow` returns a `double`, not an `int`, I think the point of OP's exercise isn't to use `Math.pow`.

Comment: @AndyTurner OP never specified that they _don't_ want to be using recursion.

Comment: The title specifies that OP *does* want (/need) to use recursion: "How to compute a power of a power using recursion?"

Comment: @AndyTurner And what if it's an X-Y problem? _Practically_ speaking, OP's approach to the solution is a poor one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Another Simple and Clear Exemple using a for Loop to calculate the Power Then Calculate the Height Using The Recursion

```
public static long exponentWithHeight(long base, long power, long height) {
            long calculatedPower;
            if (power < 0 || height < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Input; Check power and/or height value.");
            }
            if (power == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (height > 0) {
                calculatedPower = base;
                for (int i = (int) power; i > 1; i--) {
                        calculatedPower *= base;
                }
                return exponentWithHeight(calculatedPower, power, --height);
            }

            return base;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is easy to read and works like a charm.

Comment: You are welcome. but you should **Remember** that this code will only work for small power and height numbers because if you use some big number for power or height like 4 or above, the calculated number will exceed the capacity of a `long` data type Max Value and it will return 0.